# is this li-ion battery still safe to use?

Tags: batteries, safety, lithium-ion

While replacing my phone's screen I seem to have scratched and maybe damaged the battery. I don't know much about li-ion batteries so I'm wondering if it's still safe to use, or if I should look for a replacement.

[image]

Comment: "Scratched and maybe damaged" Thats an understatement if I've ever seen one

Comment: One only need the title to know the answer is no.

Comment: When I scratch my back I usually don't get to the bones.

Comment: i have a slightly scratched tv for sale cheap. only been run over by a truck once.

Comment: @VladimirCravero, my coffee almost came out my nose when i read your comment. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  That could be dangerous.  Dispose of it properly, and be more careful next time.